# EnableCDN in toolkitscriptmanager not downloading minified files

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-4.0

I have this ToolkitScriptManager in my Master page:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" ID="scrptManager" 
    LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false" ScriptMode="Release" EnableCdn="true">

    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Notice the `ScriptMode="Release"` and I have `compilation debug="false"` in my web.config

However, when the scripts get download to the client I get unminified javascripts. The ToolkitScriptManager downloads scripts from:

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/WebUIValidation.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/WebForms.js

How do I modify my ToolkitScriptManager to download minified version of these scripts?

Comment: The same to me, its seems that this webforms.js is not minified for CDN. Do you have the link that is minified ? All the rest local script are minified.

Comment: @Aristos: Yep, WebForms.js and WebUIValidation.js is no minified. I don't have which is why I posted this question? ;)

Comment: No big deal ! there are small one, and gzipped. You can also not use CDN, and get them from your computer that are included minified on other script. They will fix that in the future :)

Comment: @Aritos: even if I remove EnableCdn="true" or set it to false, it still doesn't output minified versions from DLL. It is strange. I am wondering if it is purposefully kept that way or a bug. I cannot download these 2 js files and put them in ScriptReference like http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETAjaxScriptCombiningAndMovingScriptResourceaxdsToStaticScripts.aspx because my toolkitscriptmanager is in master page and I am not sure how many controls from AjaxControlToolkit will I require in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a theory. By check the following:

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/WebForms.js
vs

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js

I noticed the MicrosoftAjax.js file it is minified, however the WebForms.js file is not. I think your set up for the ToolkitScriptManager is correct and there are some issues with cdn conent. Again it's just a guess, to be sure, maybe you can ask on  asp.net forums: http://forums.asp.net/

Hope this helps.